# Append text to description response in Woocommerce rest API

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Is it possible to add text to the "description" field in a Woocommerce rest API response?

Adding text to `the_content` using function `add_filter` does not seem to affect the API response, only the frontend render.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_rest_prepare_product_object', 'add_custom_text_to_product_descr', 10, 3 );
function add_custom_text_to_product_descr( $response, $order, $request ) {
    if ( empty( $response->data ) ) {
        return $response;
    }
    
    $custom_text = 'This text was appended using the woocommerce_rest_prepare_product_object hook.';
    
    $response->data['description'] .= $custom_text;

    return $response;
}
```